# Method reference for FileFilter Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

I have the following code for the `FileFilter`:

```
final FileFilter directoryFilter = new FileFilter()
    @Override
    public boolean accept(final File pathname)
    {
        return pathname.isDirectory();
    }
};
```

I want to write this with a method reference. This was my first try:

```
final File test;
final FileFilter directoryFilter = test::isDirectory;
```

This gives me an error:

> incompatible Types: invalid method reference.

It works if I try this with an lambda expression like:

```
final FileFilter directoryFilter = pathname -> pathname.isDirectory()
```

How must I change my code to get the method reference to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use

```
final FileFilter directoryFilter = File::isDirectory;
```

This [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) is exactly the same as the lambda expression `pathname -> pathname.isDirectory()` that you wrote.

Method references with the syntax `ContainingType::methodName` are used to reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of the `ContainingType` type.

The method reference `test::isDirectory` would actually refer to the instance method `isDirectory` on the specific `test` instance (not for an arbitrary `File` instance).